# Unsure how to simplify

Tags: fractions, cubics

I have the following equation:
$$\frac{0.8}{x+1}+\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{1.2}{(x+1)^3} = 2.5$$

According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=0.8%2F%281%2Bx%29%2B1%2F%281%2Bx%29%5E2%2B1.2%2F%281%2Bx%29%5E3+%3D+2.5), it can be simplified as follows, assuming $x$ is real:
$$\frac{1.09047}{x + 1} = 1$$

Of course it's just a rounded value, but is there some method to get this form without solving the cubic equation? I'm just curious. The initial form is so neatly arranged, I thought there might be some trick here. I'm only interested in the real solution of the equation.

Comment: You could try to solve $$\frac{a}{x+1}+\frac{b}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{c}{(x+1)^3} = d$$ and see what you find

Comment: Multiply both sides by $(x+1)^3$, then rearrange it by grouping the $x^3, x^2, x,$ and constant terms, then solve the resulting cubic equation. You'll get $1$ or $3$ solutions for $x = a$, which, if you want, you can rewrite as $\frac{a+1}{x+1} = 1$.

Comment: So I have to solve it for this form? I'm not that interested in the form. I'm only interested in the real solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Newton's method**

Let $y=x+1$. The given equation is equivalent to

$$p(y)=25y^3-8y^2 -10y-12=0.$$

The real root can be found using [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), i.e. using the recurrence relation

$$y_{n+1} = y_n - \frac{p(y_n)}{p^\prime(y_n)}$$ starting with $y_0=1$. Using [Python Sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) or whatever else, you'll find

$$\begin{aligned}y_1 &= \frac{54}{49} &= 1.10204081632653\\
y_2 &= \frac{4070958}{3732673} &= 1.09062808341368\\
y_3 &= \frac{1751267765388614226414}{1605973357978615747009} &= 1.09047124392703\\
\end{aligned}$$

*Appendix - Python code*

```
from sympy import poly, Rational, latex
from sympy.abc import x

p = poly(Rational(25, 1) * x**3 - Rational(8, 1) * x**2 - Rational(10, 1) * x - Rational(12, 1), )
pp = p.diff()

fx = x - p / pp
print(fx)

x1 = fx.subs(x, Rational(1))
print(f"y_1 &= {latex(x1)} &= {x1.evalf()}")

x2 = fx.subs(x, x1)
print(f"y_2 &= {latex(x2)} &= {x2.evalf()}")

x3 = fx.subs(x, x2)
print(f"y_3 &= {latex(x3)} &= {x3.evalf()}")
```

Comment: I'm still not sure how can I get to that simplified form. Is that possible?

Comment: Just multiply the initial equation by $10 y^3=10(x+1)^3$.

Comment: Wait. That gives me your function and the root of the second derivative is $y \approx 0.10\overline{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

Working with whole numbers and letting $t=\frac 1{x+1}$ whe need to solve for $t$ the cubic
$$12 t^3+10 t^2+8 t-25=0$$ By inspecion or graphing , we know that the root is close to $t=1$.

Consider that this is an expansion to $O(t-1)^4$
$$5+64 (t-1)+46 (t-1)^2+12 (t-1)^3+O\left((t-1)^4\right)$$ Use a series reversion to obtain
$$t=1-\frac 5{64}-\frac{575}{131072}-\frac{54125}{134217728}=\frac{123089043}{134217728}$$ Back to $x$
$$x=\frac{11128685}{123089043}=0.0904117$$

Now, suppose that we consider that it is
$$5+64 (t-1)+46 (t-1)^2+12 (t-1)^3+O\left((t-1)^6\right)$$  we shall have
$$t= \frac{516245100589197}{562949953421312}$$ and then
$$x=\frac{46704852832115}{516245100589197}=0.0904703$$

**Edit**

Zooming the graph, we know thet the solution is close to $\frac 9{10$}$. So, write again
$$-\frac{119}{125}+\frac{1379}{25} \left(t-\frac{9}{10}\right)+\frac{212}{5}
   \left(t-\frac{9}{10}\right)^2+12
   \left(t-\frac{9}{10}\right)^3+O\left(\left(t-\frac{9}{10}\right)^4\right)$$ Series reversion again gives
$$t=\frac{9}{10}+\frac{17}{985}-\frac{61268}{267588055}+\frac{72063884}{14538754757093}=\frac{26665090332931}{29077509514186}$$ and then
$$x=\frac{2412419181255}{26665090332931}=0.090471067$$

while the exact solution is $0.090471215$

Comment: So it can only be approximated without actually solving it. I see.

Comment: @Epyxoid. If you do not want to solve the cubic, yes. But I shall improve in the post